# How do I apply a Gauss Filter in Fourier Space?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft, convolution

I converted a Gauss filter, as well as an image I want to filter, into the fourier space. Are the rules of applying filters in the fourier space the same like in the image space? (e.g. just applying a convolution with np.convolve)?

Comment: No... that's why you converted both to Fourier space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Convolution theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), convolution in image space corresponds to multiplication in Fourier space.

So in order to apply the filter, you do element-wise multiplication of the Fourier-transformed image with the Fourier-transformed filter.

The product is the Fourier-transformed filtered image. To get the filtered image in image space, you apply the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: thank you! according to the article, and what you've written, I used np.multiply, and it worked! (still have to transform it back of course)